# Cron outputs to log, is there a way to make the log dynamic?

Tags: php, cron

I have a php cron job that writes its output to a log file like this:

```
crontab -l
* * * * * php -f /var/www/cron.php >> /tmp/crons/cron.log
```

Is there a way of making the log output file dynamic, so that it could write to `date('Y-m')`.cron.log?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure what cron uses to execute the commands, but in bash you could use backticks. So, with your crontab like this:

```
* * * * * bash /your/script.sh
```

and /your/script.sh containing this:

```
#!/bin/bash
php -f /var/www/cron.php >> /tmp/crons/`date +%Y-%m`.cron.log
```

you'll get that which you desire.

Comment: The alternative is to have a log rotater rename the log file afterwards and insert the date then.

Comment: @Marc B: That might be cleaner, yes. Care to post that as an answer?